# Is there a way to manage object movement toggling depend on touch count?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make my player object move right when a touch happens and move left on following touch and so on.

```
bool isTurn = true;
[SerializeField] float horizonMoveSpeed = 20f;
Vector3 targetPosWhenTrue;
Vector3 targetPosWhenFalse;


private void Start()
{
    targetPosWhenTrue = new Vector3(3f, 0, 0);
    targetPosWhenFalse = new Vector3(-3f, 0, 0);
}

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        if (isTurn == true)
        {
            transform.position += targetPosWhenTrue * Time.deltaTime * horizonMoveSpeed;
            isTurn = false;

        }
        if (isTurn == false)
        {
            transform.position += targetPosWhenFalse * Time.deltaTime * horizonMoveSpeed;
            isTurn = true;
        }
    }


}
```

There is no error message but it is not working. Does nothing.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish with that code, but I can tell you why it "Does nothing":

If your Input.touchCount is above 0 and isTurn is true (which it is), you enter the first scope where you modify the position of the object. Then you set isTurn to false and because of that, you will enter the second scope and it will be moved in the opposite direction. When the frame gets rendered (somewhere between two Update-Calls) nothing will have changed, because you added and subtracted the same value from your position.
You should overthink your algorithm.

Comment: Time.deltaTime is quite small .. plus you invert `isTurn` every frame -> you will get a forth and back jitter of a small distance ... probably looks like nothing happening

Comment: Oh ok. I understand clearly now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Since update is called every frame, isTurn is being reset every single frame. It appears that nothing is happening because it's going by so fast. In order to achieve what you're looking for you're going to have to check the position of the target and set the isTurn variable in the `else` statement. This may not be exactly what you're looking for, but should get you started.

```
if(Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    if (isTurn == true)
    {
        if(transform.position != targetPosWhenTrue)
            transform.position += targetPosWhenTrue * Time.deltaTime * horizonMoveSpeed;
        else
            isTurn = false;

    }
    if (isTurn == false)
    {
        if(transform.position != targetPosWhenTrue)
            transform.position += targetPosWhenFalse * Time.deltaTime * horizonMoveSpeed;
        else
            isTurn = true;
    }
}
```